# Start and stop accordion on responsive

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery code to make accordion for page content when window width is 500px or less. It works fine but there are few issues. When I resize window size for example from 900px to 450px and click accordion h3 link to open content it behave strangly. It opens and closes content 4 times and after it stays open, same thing when closing open accordion.

I think I'm missing something obvious here, but just could not figure out what it is.

```
jQuery(window).on("load resize",function(e){

jQuery(function() {
    if(jQuery(window).width() <= 500) {


        //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION   
        jQuery('h3').click(function() {
            if(jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
                jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
                jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
            } else {
                jQuery('h3').data('slided',false);
                jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');   
                jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
                jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
            }
        });

        //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
        jQuery(".sec").hide();
    } else { jQuery(".sec").show(); }
});
});
```

In my [JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy5pw9m/) example it seems to loop open close accordion even more.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **correct code** (you can find the [FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy5pw9m/6/)):

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION    
$('h3').click(
    function() {                   
        if (jQuery(window).width() <= 500) {                               
            if(jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
                jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
                jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
                //alert('slided');                        
            }                                
            else {
                jQuery('h3').data('slided',false);
                jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');   
                jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
                jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
            }
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Strange. On my site this code does not work at all. It does not launch accordion.

Comment: And this script should be run if window is resized - should not need to update page to get this work.

Comment: I noticed that when I use `jQuery(window).load(function ()` instead of `jQuery(window).on("load resize",function(e)` it does not open and close like "looping". But when only using load function then page need to be reloaded to get accordion working.

Comment: You might be missing either jQuery and/or jQueryUI.  You need to be loading both scripts... jQuery.js first, **THEN** jQueryUI.js.  And, yes, you should have to use the `resize` event, if you want to make it truly responsive.  You don't need to accept my answer *yet*, but can  I get an upvote at least for what I've given you so far.  I will look at it in more detail in a few hours and try to answer the rest of your questions.